# Dúvida com API do facebook

Tags: api, facebook

Estou usando a api de comentário do facebook, mas ela não é responsiva, quando a tela é pequena queria que o width da caixa fosse diferente, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a mesma dúvida no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447483/how-to-make-facebook-comments-widget-a-fluid-width). Altere as classes no seu CSS:

```
.fb-comments, 
.fb-comments iframe[style] {
    width: 100% !important;
 }
```

Tente também:

```
.fb_iframe_widget,
.fb_iframe_widget iframe[style],
.fb_iframe_widget span[style],
.fb_iframe_widget *  {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Há também uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447483/how-to-make-facebook-comments-widget-a-fluid-width/23697427#23697427) que diz o seguinte:

> This problem has been addressed by Facebook. You can now add data-width="100%" or set the width option to100% and delete any crazy js hacks as appropriate!

Numa tradução livre, é algo como:

> Este problema foi abordado pelo Facebook. Agora você pode adicionar a propriedade `width="100%"` ou definir a opção de largura para 100% e excluir qualquer hack js adicionado!

Comment: quando a tela fica responsiva fica uma barrinha embaixo para eu rolar para o lado, não quero isso, queria que ela diminuisse de acordo com o tamanho da tela, dessa maneira aí não consegui.

Comment: Funcionou Filipe, obrigada!